# tcbtheorem: How to remove parentheses from a theorem name

Tags: tcolorbox

The following code will output parentheses around the theorem name "plain".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[theorem style=plain]{plain}{}
This is my theorem. \begin{equation*} a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \end{equation*}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I want to remove these parentheses.

https://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=379

Comment: Welcome! Can you please give a complete minimal example? In particular it is necessary to know what packages you are using.

Comment: That example cannot and does not compile.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm section 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{theorem style=plain,
         description delimiters none, % <-------------
         fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,fontupper=\itshape,
         colframe=green!50!black,colback=green!10!white,
         colbacktitle=green!20!white,coltitle=blue!75!black
                                }{theo}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}{plain}{}
This is my theorem. \begin{equation*} a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \end{equation*}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}Plain.
This is my theorem. 
\begin{equation*} a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \end{equation*}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need colored box.